# Is it possible to combine multiple data frames created in loop and return a single dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Python Function returns multiple pandas dataframes but only want 1.

So I am working with json data and need to pull criteria for each object and create a dataframe. The function I built scrapes for the data and is building a dataframe, but the problem is that it is building a data frame for EACH object when I just want one.

For example, I want:

| Object | Name. | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Alice | 10/13 |
| B | Ben | 11/4 |
| C | Caleb | 11/6 |

Instead, I am getting 3 different data frames:

| Object | Name. | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Alice | 10/13 |

| Object | Name. | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B. | Ben | 11/4 |

| Object | Name. | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | Caleb | 11/6 |

Currently my code:

```
for data in list_json[0]["changelog"]["histories"]:      
            if (data["items"][0]["field"] == "issuetype" and data["items"][0]["from"] == "10901"):
                storyDict[each]["Name"] = data["name"]                                                                      
            if (data["items"][0]["field"] == "Date" and data["items"][0]["to"] == "1942"):
                storyDict[each]["Date"] = data["date"]
            df = pd.DataFrame(storyDict)
            df1 = df.T
            df_reorder = pd.DataFrame()    
            for j in ["Name", "Date"] :
                if j in df1.columns :
                df_reorder[j] = df1[j]
```

Any suggestions? Is there a way to possibly merge all dataframes within the function I used? They do not have distinct names as they are in a for loop.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "in a for loop"? Are you building a list of data frames, or are you simply assigning each data frame to the same variable on each iteration, overwriting the frame from the previous iteration? Please provide a [mcve] to show how you are generating the three data frames in the first place.

Comment: I added some sample code, thanks @chepner

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier to see what your code looks like but it sounds like you want to append each objects to your list.

maybe something like this?

```
    data = [] 
    for obj in objects:
        name = obj['name']
        date = obj['date']
        
        # "merging" as you referred it
        data.append({'Object': obj['object'], 'Name': name, 'Date': date})
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```